# How can I find the distribution for the number of years until the first year's rainfall is exceeded for the first time?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sampling

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be jointly continuous and independently distributed with marginal pdf $f(x)$, where each $X_i$ represents annual rainfall at a given location. How can I find the distribution for the number of years until the first year's rainfall $(X_1)$ is exceeded for the first time?

I assume this is a fairly straight forward problem, but I am failing to see what the most logical first step would be. How would you go about thinking of the first step?

Comment: "independent" and also "identical"?  The "identical" changes the complexity of this problem considerably.

Comment: @Him - the fact that all the $X_i$ have the same marginal PDF and are independent implies identical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let us assume that annual rainfall can be considered a continuous variable (which requires the probability of no rainfall in a year to be equal to zero.)  The following steps get us to our goal:

1. The first year's rainfall has cumulative distribution function
   $F(X_1)$, and, as is well-known, $F(X_1) \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ (the [Probability Integral Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform))
2. The probability that any given successive year's rainfall exceeds the
   first year's rainfall is  $1-F(X_1)$, label it $p$.  (This is because the probability of any given successive year's rainfall being $\leq$ year 1's rainfall is $F(X_1)$, so the probability of exceeding it is just $1-F(X_1)$.) Since $F(X_1)
   \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$, $p$ is too; $1 - $ a $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$ variate is also a  $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$ variate.
3. The number of years ($k$) until the first exceedence of the first
   year's rainfall, conditional upon $p$, has a Geometric distribution with probability parameter $p$: $p(k | p) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$.

To remove the conditioning upon $p$, we integrate the Geometric distribution with respect to the Uniform distribution on $p$, which "disappears" in the expression below because it is equal to $1$ everywhere:

$$p(k) =  \int_0^1(1-p)^{k-1}p\text{d}p$$

which is the $\text{Beta}(2,k)$ function.  Expanding this function leads to:

$$p(k) = {1 \over k(k+1)}, \, k \geq 1$$

A quick check in R that this (plausibly) does sum to $1$:

```
> sum(beta(2,1:100000))
[1] 0.99999
```

Comment: So $p(k)=\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$ is the distribution, where $k \ge 0$, correct? Also, how do you know $F(X_1) \sim U(0,1)$?

Comment: Also, I don't understand your (2) entirely. How do you make those claims?

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your questions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for adding the link and a bit of an explanation in #2. I did not know about that 1 - $U(0,1) \sim U(0,1)$. That seems like a nice property to know!

Comment: There is an unstated premise in this analysis that all years' chances of exceeding the first years' rainfall are i.i.d.

Comment: @Him - the OP has said the $X_i$ are i.i.d., that's sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

*jbowman's answer is correct, though there is an alternative approach to the same answer*

By symmetry/exchangeability and assuming a continuous distribution so no ties, the probability that $X_1$ is the largest of $\{X_1,X_2,\cdots X_n\}$ is $\frac1n$ and the probability that $X_1$ is the largest of $\{X_1,X_2,\cdots X_n, X_{n+1}\}$ is $\frac1{n+1}$.

This means the probability $X_{n+1}$ is the first value to exceed $X_1$ is $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}.$

Slightly counter-intuitively,  this implies that the expected number of years until $X_1$ is exceeded is therefore infinite.  Suppose $X_{n+1}$ is the first to exceed $X_1$, which takes $n$ years to happen.  Then the expected number of years is $\sum\limits_1^\infty n \times \frac1{n(n+1)} = \sum\limits_1^\infty \frac1{n+1}$ and this is infinite.

Comment: Elegant!  (+1)  I think you could also have done it with the second "probability that $X_1$ is the..." replaced by "probability that $X_{n+1}$ is the largest...", then just multiplied the two probabilities, since they are clearly independent.

Comment: @jbowman that works too - both working allows independence to be proved formally, and settle any doubts of somebody who thinks perhaps $X_1$ being high (if it is the highest of the first $n$) makes it less likely $X_{n+1}$ will exceed it

Comment: Why do you subtract $\frac{1}{n+1}$ from $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @Edison Clearly if $X_1$ is the largest of $\{X_1,X_2,\cdots X_n, X_{n+1}\} $ then $X_1$ must be the largest of $\{X_1,X_2,\cdots X_n\}$.  So the event $X_{n+1}$ being the first to exceed $X_1$ is the event that $X_1$ is the largest of $\{X_1,X_2,\cdots X_n\}$ excluding the event where  $X_1$ is the largest of $\{X_1,X_2,\cdots X_n, X_{n+1}\} $ too;

Comment: I'm trying to formulate this concept into an equation, since English is a tricky language for me. So $P(X_1 < X_{n+1}, X_1 > X_i)=P(X_1>X_i)-P(X_{n+1}>X_1)$, where $i=1,\cdots,n$ just does not make mathematical sense to me yet. How would you formulate this? Thank you!

Comment: @Edison Try writing $X_1 = \max\limits_{1 \le i \le n} (X_i)$ to say $X_1$ is the largest of the first $n$ $X_i$s.  Then the following three equations are true as the first says either $X_1 \gt X_{n+1}$ or $X_1 < X_{n+1}$ and the others are rearrangements with the third being what we want

Comment: $\mathbb P(X_1 = \max\limits_{1 \le i \le n} (X_i)) = \mathbb P(X_1 = \max\limits_{1 \le i \le n} (X_i)\gt X_{n+1}) +\mathbb P(X_1 = \max\limits_{1 \le i \le n} (X_i)\lt X_{n+1})$ 
$\mathbb P(X_1 = \max\limits_{1 \le i \le n} (X_i)) = \mathbb P(X_1 = \max\limits_{1 \le i \le n+1} (X_i)) +\mathbb P(X_{n+1} \gt X_1 = \max\limits_{1 \le i \le n} (X_i))$ 
$\mathbb P(X_{n+1} \gt X_1 = \max\limits_{1 \le i \le n} (X_i)) = \mathbb P(X_1 = \max\limits_{1 \le i \le n} (X_i)) -\mathbb P(X_1 = \max\limits_{1 \le i \le n+1} (X_i))$

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thanks for putting it this way.

Comment: @Henry can you expand on the expected number of years being infinite?

Comment: @xabush I have added to the final paragraph

Comment: Thanks. It's clearer now